# Is the CIL evaluation stack op change description "PopI8+Pop8" a spec bug?

Tags: .net, specifications, cil

In the CIL/MSIL [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-335/) spec, there's a list of descriptions used in the [opcode.def](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.0/src/coreclr/inc/opcode.def) file `Stack Behaviour` column to describe what values are popped off the runtime stack for each op. Page 483 of the spec:

> ### VI.C.2 CIL opcode descriptions
>
> Data removed from the stack to compute this operations result. The possible values here are the following: 
> ... 
> h. PopI8+Pop8 – Top of stack is an 8-byte integer, next is a native pointer 
> i. PopI+PopR4 – Top of stack is a 4-byte floating point number, next is a native pointer 
> j. PopI+PopR8 – Top of stack is an 8-byte floating point number, next is a native pointer 
> ... 
> n. PopRef+PopI+PopI8 – Top of stack is an 8-byte integer, then a native-sized integer, then an object reference

It seems that `h. PopI8+Pop8` is a spec bug. In all the `OPDEF()` macros there's no references to `Pop8`, so it's not a "possible value." Based on the `h.` text description and inferring from the rest of the spec:

- "Top of stack is an 8-byte integer" -> `PopI8`
- next is a native pointer -> `PopI`

Then the value for `h.` should be `PopI+PopI8`?

That matches the [`stind.i8` op code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.0/src/coreclr/inc/opcode.def):

```
OPDEF(CEE_STIND_I8,                   "stind.i8",         PopI+PopI8,         Push0,       InlineNone,         IPrimitive,  1,  0xFF,    0x55,    NEXT)
```

as `PopI+PopI8` isn't in the list with the other descriptions.

---

If this is a bug, is there some errata on ECMA or MSDN or GitHub that lists the fixes?

Comment: Guessing it's a bug. but the whole section is only informative text anyway, so it doesn't really matter

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1a83f61a5a3368250e5bed2baf28aed0f9e59508/src/mono/mono/cil/opcode.def#L87

Comment: @HansPassant That was linked already. That says `PopI+PopI8` not `PopI8+Pop8`